# The comment/cdata syntax spec in html?

Tags: html

I found that latest version of Chrome treats anything like `<! data >` as a comment section. What is the spec? I cannot find it at https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html. In this spec, the `Comment` must start with `<!--`, end with `-->`, and `CDATASection` is not deprecated, must start with `<![CDATA[`, end with `]]>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/twnbjah5/

Comment: I’d consider that a bug in Chrome ... But since it is not valid HTML5 to begin with, I would perhaps not consider it something to complain about either.

Comment: @CBroe: Nope, expected behavior. See the duplicate.